# Files showing up in every branch in git

Tags: git

I've used git for a couple of years now.  Either some brain cells died, or something else is going on.  Please bear with me.

I've created a couple of branches.  When I change to one branch, say, `git checkout example1`, and create a file: `touch test`, then change to a different branch, `git checkout example2`, `test` now shows up in the example2 branch.  That's not what I expected to happen.  Is this normal?  If not, what might cause it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not being tracked by git. So, if you change branches, git doesn't know with which branch that file should be associated and that's why un-versioned files will be moving with you as you change branches.

To get rid of your problem, either remove that file ***test*** or commit it when you are on your desired branch.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't commit a change, it will stay visible across different checkouts.
Checking out a different branch does not delete un-versioned files in the working directory.

If you commit the test file on your example1 branch and then switch to example2 everything should work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, expected behaviour. `git` doesn't automatically track new files -- you have to tell it to using `git add`/`git commit`. If you create a new file, don't tell `git` to track it, and then switch branches, `git` won't complain -- that file isn't doing anything or causing any harm. As long as the filename doesn't conflict with a file that has been committed on the `example2` branch, that untracked file will sit there, happy as a clam, until you decide to add it to the repo.